# R code, Finding general transition variables for Threshold AutoRegressive Processes

Tags: r, tar, varying

The following is a code to find the optimal "threshold variable" given an AR(pmax). The variable coefficient AR is a generalization of TAR in that it for more complex smooth dynamics.  Pmax controls AR(pmax). P is the maximum lag of the first component. Q is the maximum lag of the second component. R is the maximum power of the second component.

The a[i,j,k] is the variable in the functional coefficient ==> X(t)=F0(a[i,j,k])+ F1(a[i,j,k])*X(t-1)+..+ Fm(a[i,j,k])*X(t-m) instead of the classic AR(m) X(t)=a0+a1*X(t-1)+..+am*X(t-m). I plan on finding a general transition variable using a triple loop and that is the reason why it is a[i,j,k]= X(t-i)*X^k(t-j)

```
    library(gamlss)
    library(gamlss.add)
    library(gam)
    library(mgcv)
    library(tsDyn)

    llynx=log10(lynx)


    minAICVCsplinetest=function(x,pmax,p,q,r){
    blagg=na.remove(blag(x,pmax))
    data=na.remove(blag(x,pmax))
    alpha=array(0,dim=c(p,q,r))
    a=rep(0, length(data[,c(1)]))

    for(i in 1:p){
    for(j in 1:q){
    for(k in 1:r){
    a[i,j,k]=blagg[,c(i)]*blagg[,c(j)]^k
    for(m in 1:pmax){ll[m]=to.string(bquote("s(a[i,j,k],by=data[,c("~.(m)~"+1)])+"))}
    gg=to.string((gsub( "[^][:alnum:],=()[+]", "", (ll))))
    alpha[i,j,k]=AIC(gam(blagg[,c(1)]~cat(substr(gg, 1, nchar(gg)-1))))}}}
    which(alpha==min(alpha), arr.ind=TRUE)}

    minAICVCsplinetest(llynx,6,4,4,10)
```

The optimal policy would probably be to show the transition variable with lowest effective degree of freedom but the problem I am having is following: Error in a[i, j, k] = blagg[, c(i)] * blagg[, c(j)]^k : incorrect number of subscripts. Thank you for your time and consideration